# find uniq lines in file, but ignore certain columns

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I've looked around now for a few hours but haven't found anything helpful.

I want to sort through a file that has a large number of lines formatted like

```
Values1, values2, values3, values4, values5, values6,
```

but I want to return only the lines that are uniquely related to

```
Values1, values2, values3, values6
```

As in I have multiple instances Values1, values2, values3, values6 where their only difference is values4, values5 and I don't want to return those, rather just one instance of the line (preferably the line pertaining to the largest value of values4, values5 but thats not a big deal)

I have tried using
    uniq -s ##
but that doesn't work because my values lengths are variable.

I have also tried 
    sort -u -k 1,3 
but that doesn't seem to work either.

mainly my issue is my values are variable in length, I'm not that concerned with sorting by values6 but it would be nice.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: fixed it, I hit tab twice and enter on accident before I was finished!

Answer (score 1):

With awk, you can print the first time the "key" is seen:

```
awk '
    { key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $6 }
    !seen[key]++
' file
```

The magic `!seen[key]++` is an awk idiom. It returns true only the first time that key is encountered. It then increments the values so that it won't be true for any subsequent encounter.

Comment: I like that idea, but I need to sort through about 2000 lines, with about 500 unique lines with respect to values1,values2,values3,values6.  There are 4 duplicates of each values1, values2, values3, values6 where the only difference is the values4, values5. so I want to return about 500 unique lines.  would this not reset once a different values1, values2, values3, values6 are seen and thus the next time that set is seen it will not realize it has already seen it?

Comment: No, awk uses associative arrays, and it's not going to spontaneously forget what elements are in the array. Did you try it? 2000 lines is a trivial amount of input, unless your computer has very very little memory.

Comment: Also if you state your requirements more clearly, I can help you with the "max" and "sorting" of the output. What's the "maximum of value4,value5"?

Comment: no I have not tried it, its a short script I need to right for work and I already left for the day, but I will try it first thing in the morning.
Also the maximum of value4 is "th: 0xFFFFFFFF" and value5 is "sh: 0xFFFFFFFF" both "th: " and "sh: " are fixed, only the hex changes.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

alternative to `awk`

```
cut -d" " -f1-3,6 filename | sort -u
```

extract only required fields, sort unique

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely mustn't use the very clean `cut` method as suggested by @karafka, then with a csv file as input, you could use `uniq -f <num>` which skips the first `<num>` columns for the uniqueness comparison.

Since uniq expects blanks as separators we need to change this and also reorder the columns to meet your requirements.

```
sed 's/,/\t/g' textfile.csv | awk '{ print $4,$5,$1,$2,$3,$6}' | \
 sort -k3,4,5,6 | uniq -f 2 | \ 
 awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} { print $3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}'
```

This way only first line values (after sort) of $4 and $5 will be printed.